# How to increase buffer size of gl2ps renderer

Tags: octave

I make videos out of png files created by octave, through the print command.  Sometimes the created image can be large enough that octave has to bump the gl2ps buffer size a couple of times, accompanied by the warning:

```
GL2PS info: OpenGL feedback buffer overflow
warning: gl2ps_renderer::draw: retrying with buffer size: 8.4E+06 B
GL2PS info: OpenGL feedback buffer overflow
warning: gl2ps_renderer::draw: retrying with buffer size: 1.7E+07 B
```

Because I am creating thousands of images, a lot of time is being wasted, trying various buffer sizes that are known to be too small.  Is there any way telling print what buffer size to request for the duration of a run?

Comment: @Andy I use Octave 4.4.1 on Debian Buster.  Each frame is made with eval(['print -dpng ' fname ' -r100']); Those files are concatenated by ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i IMG%04d.png -vf scale=1080:-1 -crf 19 Re100N1.mp4.  If it helps I can include a MWE of the script that makes the files

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there a reason you dont use getframe and then imwrite or directly create the video using the video package?

Comment: @Andy The reason is that I did not know these functions existed.  I will find out.  However as a general comment it would be useful if the user could help gl2ps from guessing at the buffer size, if previous experience suggests what is needed, What I am thinking about is an entry in get(gcf.... ???

Comment: For the gl2ps buffer overflow: The behavior was changed for the next stable release 5.x. You can have a look at the code here https://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/ebf5e6ffd578/libinterp/corefcn/gl2ps-print.cc#l316

Comment: For the topic "howto create a mp4 video out of Octave/via plot" you may create another question where I can provide some code. I saw some youtube videos from a user called Clinton Winant showing vortexes. If you've already have the image there is no need to go through plot and gl2ps which calls ghostscript under the hood

Comment: @Andy Thanks so much, I will put a new question very soon.  Yes those are my videos, and yes I need a faster way of making them.

Comment: @Andy Just so you know I framed a new question over an hour ago, but I see it hasn't been posted yet.